# How to refresh a parent page when closing an iframe - jquery

Tags: jquery

i need to refresh my webpage when the user close an iframe

```
var iframe = $('#layer-frame').contents();

iframe.find(".close").click(function(){
  alert("test");
});
```

I have the above code which doesnt seem to capture my click event. How to add the functionality of page refresh..please help

Comment: Did you receive any error in the console?

Comment: nope no error at all :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some trick - you can try to catch frame bubbling click event -

**Parent page**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>testpage</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                var frame = window.frames[0] // first in may case

                $(frame).on("click", function(e){

                    if($(e.target).is('.close')){
                        window.location.reload();
                    }

                });
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div><iframe src="iframe.html"/></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**iframe**

```
<div class="root">
    <span class="close">click</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the code in iframe load function:

```
$('#layer-frame').load(function() {
   $(this).contents().find(".close").click(function(){
      alert("test");
      location.reload(true); 
   });
});
```

Comment: is #layer-frame iframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var ifra = $('#layer-frame').contents();
ifra.find(".close").click(function(){
  location.reload(true); // This will reload the current page
});
```

Comment: like i mentioned..i cannot capture any event in my handler :(

Comment: @Evgeniy it will return

Comment: ifra.find(".close") returns Object[]

Comment: it doesent return $(.close) - it returns empty, you can easily test it