# How can I add events for elements inside an iframe from the parent document with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have an iframe for which I need to bind a click Backbone View Event to some of its DOM elements.

I tried with something like this, but it doesn't event make any sense:

```
 el: $('#app'),
 events:{
   'click #iframe .button1': 'clickEvent'
 }
```

Do you guys know how to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible using `events` property. If you have an access to the iframe you can do it manually, like this:

```
this.$('#iframe').contents().find('.button1').on('click', this.clickEvent)
```

Comment: And where do I have to add this line of code exactly?

Comment: Inside the view when your iframe will be ready for DOM queries.

Comment: looks like this will not work checkout similar post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834000/how-to-refresh-a-parent-page-when-closing-an-iframe-jquery/22834914#22834914

Comment: Do we need to unbind them as they are bound to elements inside an iframe.