# How to reload principal page after close iframa

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to reload my principal page after close iframe. I use jquery to open modal and .html() to add iframe html parameters.

This open when I do click on my id  a href="#ex2"

`<div><a href="#ex2" rel="modal:open" >Prueba de Maquillaje</a></div>`

This call my funcion and add the iframe on my id idcart

````
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Modal -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
    <script>

                $('.close-modal ').click(function() {
                        location.reload();
                        });
                var requestOptions = {method:'GET', redirect:'follow'};
                fetch("https://modiface--locatelcolombia.myvtex.com/api/checkout/pub/orderForm/", requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(function(r) {
                    cartId = r['orderFormId'];
                    $("#idCart").html("<iframe src='http://localhost:81/proyectoModiface/modiface/index.php?cartId="+cartId+"' class='frameModiface' id='pruebasId' allow='camera' name='iframe_a'></iframe>");
                    
                });
             
    </script>``` 

This is my idCart div id 

``` <div id="ex2" class="modal"><div id="idCart"></div></div>```
````

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22834914/14300834

Comment: Thanks a lot but doesn't work